# Content script isn't running in iframe within another extension's page

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

Suppose that 2 extensions are installed in Google Chrome.

---

1st extension runs content.js on w3.org:

manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": [ "https://www.w3.org/*" ],
    "all_frames": true,
    "js": [ "content.js" ]
}]
```

content.js:

```
alert('content');
```

---

2nd extension has page.html, which loads w3.org into iframe:

manifest.json:

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["page.html"]
```

page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<iframe src="https://www.w3.org/"></iframe>
```

---

Now enter in address bar `chrome-extension://2nd-extension-id/page.html`. You will see w3.com, but content.js was not running (no `alert()` window). I do not see errors in console.

The question is: how to permit content script to run in this iframe?

---

**I created [Chrome issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=599167#c3). Status: WontFix, unfortunately. But this is can be changed in future...**

Comment: You simply can't.  Extensions cannot run in other extensions.  Allowing such a thing would make it possible for malevolent extensions to do some very bad things.

Comment: @Marc Guiselin, no. w3.org is not part of extension and is running in own context with standard permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't with extensions but you could do something similiar in Google Apps:
you can use [webview](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview) instead of iframe. Therefore you can inject script through `executeScript` method.

Comment: However, `<webview>` is only available to Chrome Apps and not extensions.